# Python argparse handling booleans

Tags: python, argparse

Title is very vague but my i don't know how to succinctly word my problem.

i want to add a flag to my script that will accept a boolean or if the boolean isn't provided default to True. That part is simple enough but i also want it to hold a seperate value if the flag is not provided by the user such as None. Essentially holding three different values.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

######
## prefered method
######
def t_or_f(arg):
    arg_str = str(arg)
    print(f"evaluating {arg_str}")
    if arg_str == "None":
        return True
    if arg_str.lower() == "true":
        return True
    if arg_str.lower() == "false":
        return False

parser.add_argument(
    "--follow-lib",
    type=t_or_f,
    nargs='?',
)

args, leftover = parser.parse_known_args()

print(args.follow_lib)
```

This code is close to what i want to achieve however, `python scipt.py --follow-lib' gives me None and i want it to be True. It is not running the t_or_f() func when no value is given to the flag.

i know the python way of achieving this is to use two flags such as:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
    "--follow-lib",
    action='store_true',
    default=None
)
parser.add_argument(
    '--no-follow-lib',
    action='store_false',
    dest='follow_lib'
)

args, leftover = parser.parse_known_args()

print(args.follow_lib)
```

The above code achieves what i want inside the script but i do not want to use two flags if i can avoid it. Is there a way of getting the same results with just one flag?

Ultimately i want the following behavior:

`python script.py`                             -> None

`python script.py --follow-lib`                -> True

`python script.py --follow-lib=True`           -> True

`python script.py --follow-lib=False`          -> False

Thanks

Comment: in your `t_or_f` example... you're getting None because it's set to be None by default in the place where you define the argument. Change it to True and it should work

Comment: With `nargs='?'` you should define both a `default` and a `const`.  Those will handle the cases where it isn't used at all or used without an following string.  Then `type` only has to handle the case with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass no arguments the function will never be called.

Not sure if something like this is what you are looking for

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


######
## prefered method
######
parser.add_argument(
    "--follow-lib",
    default=True,
    nargs='?',
)

args = parser.parse_args()
arg_str = str(args.follow_lib)

# If true or no argument provided enabled the flag and run some function
if arg_str.lower() == "true" or args.follow_lib is None:
  print("Flag Enabled")

# if flag is disable do nothing i guess
if arg_str.lower() == "false":
  print("Flag disabled")

args, leftover = parser.parse_known_args()

print(args.follow_lib)
```

Comment: Add a `const` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the `--follow-lib` option does not follow by any argument, the function `t_or_f` does not get called, thus you get `None` instead of `True`. One way to deal with this issue is to use a custom `Action` class:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import json


class TrueFalseNone(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values == None:
            # Case: no argument
            value = True
        else:
            value = json.loads(values.lower())

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, value)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--follow-lib",
    nargs="?",
    action=TrueFalseNone,
)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Sample interactions:

```bash
$ ./main.py 
Namespace(follow_lib=None)

$ ./main.py --follow-lib
Namespace(follow_lib=True)

$ ./main.py --follow-lib=True
Namespace(follow_lib=True)

$ ./main.py --follow-lib=False
Namespace(follow_lib=False)
```

#### Notes

- The `__call__` method, unlike `t_or_f`, is always called
- I use the `json.loads` as a convenient way to parse the bool string

#### Alternative

While the above work, I don't like it because it takes a lot of code to get it working just right. For that, I would like to propose an alternative, which uses `argparse.BooleanOptionalAction`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# The BooleanOptionalAction will generate 2 options:
# --follow-lib    --> True
# --no-follow-lib --> False
parser.add_argument(
    "--follow-lib",
    action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction,
    default=None,
)

def tryout(argv):
    options = parser.parse_args(argv)
    print(f"\n# {argv}")
    print(options)

tryout(None)
tryout(["--follow-lib"])
tryout(["--no-follow-lib"])
```

Output:

```
# None
Namespace(follow_lib=None)

# ['--follow-lib']
Namespace(follow_lib=True)

# ['--no-follow-lib']
Namespace(follow_lib=False)
```

#### Notes

- I believe this design is cleaner and you still have `None`, `True`, and `False`
- I like the separation between `--follow-lib` and `--no-follow-lib`